# Elasticsearch between query for 2 fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I would like to query ElasticSearch (with below data) with `3 bedrooms` and expect the output to return ids: 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25.

```
|   id   | bedrooms_min | bedrooms_max |
________________________________________
|   20   |       1      |       4      |
|   21   |       1      |       3      |
|   22   |       3      |       4      |
|   23   |       2      |       3      |
|   24   |       3      |       3      |
|   25   |       2      |       5      |
|   26   |       4      |       5      |
|   27   |       1      |       1      |
|   28   |       1      |       2      |
|   29   |       2      |       2      |
________________________________________
```

because:

1. ID 20: 3 is between 1 and 4.
2. ID 21: bedrooms_max is equal to 3.
3. ID 22: bedrooms_min is equal to 3.
4. ID 23: bedrooms_max is equal to 3.
5. ID 24: `bedrooms_min = bedrooms_max = 3`
6. ID 25: 3 is between 2 and 5.
7. ID 26: 3 is out of range

Some sort of `BETWEEN` query I am looking for!

Is it possible? So far I tried with `multi_match` query but that's not giving me IDs: 20 and 25 and I doubt that this resultset can be achieved with multi_match query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query would do the trick I think. What it does is basically find all documents having `bedrooms_min <= 3 AND bedrooms_max >= 3` which is what you expect:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "bedrooms_min": {
              "lte": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "bedrooms_max": {
              "gte": 3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

An even better solution would be to model your bedroom as a [`integer_range` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) so you can run a [simple intersecting `range` query](https://www.elastic.co/blog/numeric-and-date-ranges-in-elasticsearch-just-another-brick-in-the-wall) on it.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have added some more example data in my post. I am going to try your answer now and also checking the links. Please let me know if you think solution might need tweaks based on sample data

Comment: Try it out and let us know, it should work

Comment: I need your advise on how it works for input ranges for example:  1-2, 1-3, 2-3 etc.? Let' say if I search for 2 -3 bedrooms then the results IDs would be: 21, 22,  23, 24, 25, 28, 29

Comment: It would work if you set it up as described in the last sentence of my answer. Feel free to create a new thread and expose your need so we can solve it.